# How to generate equivalent query by LINQ c#

Tags: c#, linq

this is my in-line sql query. the same equivalent query i like to generated by LINQ.

```
var lowerPageBoundary = 0;
var tableName = "Orders";
var columnToSortBy = "OrderID";
var sortColumn = "OrderID";
var rowsPerPage = 16;
var CommaSeparatedListOfColumnNames = "OrderID,CustomerID,EmployeeID ";

var SQL = "Select Top " + rowsPerPage + " " +
    CommaSeparatedListOfColumnNames + " From " + tableName +
    " WHERE " + columnToSortBy + " NOT IN (SELECT TOP " +
    lowerPageBoundary + " " + columnToSortBy + " From " +
    tableName + " Order By " + sortColumn +
    ") Order By " + sortColumn;
```

this is my LINQ query so far. just tell me how to customize it to get output like above in-line sql query.

```
    XDocument document = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
    var query = from r in document.Descendants("orders")
        select new
        {
            OrderID = r.Element("OrderID").Value,
            CustomerID = r.Element("CustomerID").Value,
            EmployeeID = r.Element("EmployeeID").Value
        };
    query = query.OrderBy(sortColumn + " " + OrderDirection);
```

how to make it nested like above sql query and add the pagination concept like above sql one.

Comment: can you post the generated SQL? it's easier to convert when you can see that

Comment: use take and skip to page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be easier if you post the original SQL query, but here's my take:

```
document
.Where(x=> !documents.OrderBy(p=> p.OrderID)
                     .Take(sortColumn)
                     .Contains(x))
.Select(p=> new {...})
.OrderBy(...).Take(...)
```

EDIT:

Or better yet:

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<Whatever>(
                     documents.OrderBy(p=> p.OrderID)
                              .Take(sortColumn));
document
.Where(x=> !hashSet.Contains(x))
.Select(p=> new {...})
.OrderBy(...).Take(...)
```